# Setting column type to boolean in RedBeanPHP

Tags: php, postgresql, boolean, redbean

I want to store a boolean value of a bean in a PostgreSQL database, but I am getting an integer column being created by RedBeanPHP.

I've tried the following so far:

```
$b = R::dispense("bean");
$b->setMeta("bean.test", "boolean");
$b->test = false;

$id = R::store($b);
var_dump(R::load("bean", $id));
```

The column `test` is now of type `integer`, but I would expect it to be `boolean`. `R::load` returns the `false` value of the column as a string: `"0"`. Without `setMeta` it does not work either.

Comment: Redbean works better in mysql for column types, on Postgres it`s a little messy, anyway, using integer os smallint for boolean values is a common practice, but, if you want to use boolean instead, you'll have to change it manually on database.

Comment: Types are data representation that allows interactions using operators and functions. Using a tiny int in place of a real boolean _is_ a lousy hack. I understand why m13r is worried to get a string '0' instead of a real false boolean.

Comment: Exactly. For now I have something like `($b->test === "0") ? false : true` after loading the bean but that is not nice. On the other hand Postgres returns boolean values as characters `'t'` or `'f'` (with native PHP functions) which would RedBean have to handle with.